# 100% width not consistent on mobile webkit - Apple devices only

Tags: iphone, html, css, mobile, mobile-webkit

I'm working on a webpage for a client and I'm creating a mobile responsive version for them.

I've worked through most of the website, however, upon loading my 'Services' page, there is an eyesore of a gap all along the right side of the page. Strange, because it uses the same CSS as all the other pages, which all display at full 100% width.

Devices tested with:
iPhone 4 - Chrome, Safari
iPhone 5 - Chrome, Safari

I've also tested this with a Samsung S3, but in Chrome it seems to load fine.

In addition, I've tested it using the Safari developer tools and inspected the page. 
It seems as if the HTML from the get go isn't conforming to the 100%. 
I've got no idea how to fix this!

The page is http://temp3.advisible.com.au/services

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What if you add initial-scale=1 in the viewport meta?

Comment: i've already tried that, unfortunately, that does nothing

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to solve this problem for anybody who has this issue in the future.

I used a Wordpress page selector and changed the html width of the page.

A messy solution, but it works.

```
<?php 
if (is_page('services')) {
    echo "<style> 
                @media only screen 
                and (min-width : 320px) 
                and (max-width : 480px) 
                {html {width: 340px; }}
        </style>";
  }
?>
```